# Получение значений из таблиц со степенью связи много ко многим

Tags: запрос, sql

Есть две таблицы, со степенью связи много ко многим. Соответственно между ними есть таблица, которая и обеспечивает эту степень связи. ТаблицаА содержит информацию о контактных лицах, ТаблицаБ информацию о телефонах. Одному контактному лицу может соответствовать от 1 до 4 телефонов, а телефон может соответствовать любому количеству контактных лиц. А ТаблицаВ, соответсвенно, обеспечивает связь. Задача состоит в написании запроса для отобраения информации о контактных лицах, т.е. его имя и все телефоны привязанные к нему. Я знаю как сделать запрос, результат которого будет выглядеть так

Имя    | Телефон

Петров | 111111

Петров | 222222

Петров | 333333

Иванов | 555555

Иванов | 666666

и т.д.

А надо чтобы результирующая таблица имела вид:

Имя    | Телефон1 | Телефон2 | Телефон3 | Телефон4

Петров | 111111   | 222222   | 333333   | NULL

Иванов | 555555   | 666666   | NULL     | NULL

и т.д.

Не могу сообразить как построить запрос. Буду признателен за любую помощь:)

**UPD** СУБД - MS SQL Server 2008
[image]

Comment: Хотя бы описание таблиц -- в студию!

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В зависимости от СУБД можно использовать CASE или PIVOT.
Например, так:

```
select name, 
max(case num when 1 then ph end) phone1, max(case num when 2 then ph end) phone2,
max(case num when 3 then ph end) phone3, max(case num when 4 then ph end) phone4
from(
select b.id,b.name, p.cityphonenumber ph, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.id order by bp.phonesref) num
from brokersphone bp join brokers b on b.id = bp.brokersref join phones p on p.id = bp.phonesref
) X
group by id,name
```

--Pivot--

```
select name,
[1],[2],[3],[4]
from(
select b.id,b.name, p.cityphonenumber ph, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.id order by bp.phonesref) num
from brokersphone bp join brokers b on b.id = bp.brokersref join phones p on p.id = bp.phonesref
) X
pivot (max(ph) for num in([1],[2],[3],[4])) pvt
```

Comment: Как это примерно будет выглядеть для MS SQL Server?

Comment: Через case написал в ответе. Пивот тоже

Comment: Примного благодарен:) То что нужно